# Return control to parent window after oauth login in popup

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, dojo

I have read about window.opener, but it does not seem to work for me.

Basic idea: Open popup that makes the user sign into an oauth2 system.(google, box, etc)
All I care from there, is getting the url since it has the access token, token type and expiration.

With this code, google url opens up fine, and I can login(and also close popup) but cannot pass the url to other methods.

Handler on button click:

```
var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope="+ scope +
"&redirect_uri="+ redirect_uri +
"&response_type=token&client_id=" + client_id;

this.oauthSignIn(url, redirect_uri).then(
 lang.hitch(this, function (data) {
  console.log("here 0 " + data);
  this._getTokenValue(data, 'access_token').then(function (data1) {
   console.log("here 2 " + data1);
  });
 }),
);
```

Console.log prints the url as expected, but the same "data" cannot be passed to this_getTokenValue no matter what I try.

this.oauthSigin:

```
oauthSignIn: function(url, redirect_uri) {
 var dfd = new Deferred();
 var win = window.open(url, "_blank", 'width=800, height=600');
 var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
  try {
   if (win.document.URL.indexOf(redirect_uri) != -1) {
    window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
    win.close();
    dfd.resolve(win.document.URL);
   }
  } catch(e) {
 }
},100);
return dfd;
}
```

I cannot never seem to be able to pass url this this function.

```
_getTokenValue: function(url, name) {
  var dfd = new Deferred();
  name = name.replace(/[[]/,"\[").replace(/[]]/,"\]");
  var regexS = "[\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( url );
  if( results == null )
      dfd.resolve("");
  else
      dfd.resolve(results[1]);

  console.log("here1 " + results);
  return dfd;
},
```

Any help pointers?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if (win.document.URL.indexOf(redirect_uri) != -1) {
  window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
  var d = win.document.URL;
  win.close();
  dfd.resolve(d);
}
```